# Let f be a mean 0 variance 1 density. What's the variance of g(x)=f{(x−μ)/σ}/σ?

Tags: variance, mean

Let f be a mean 0 variance 1 density. Let $g(x) = f\{ (x - \mu) / \sigma \} / \sigma$.  What is the mean and variance associated with g?

Comment: This is essentially a question about [location and scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family)

Answer (score 0):

For **mean**:

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f\{ (x - \mu) / \sigma \}  / \sigma dx $

for change of variable $z = (x - \mu) / \sigma$ and $dz = 1/\sigma$:

$  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (z\sigma + \mu) f(z) dz $

$ = \sigma \int_{-\infty}^\infty z f(z) dz +  \mu \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z) dz = \mu$

since $ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty z f(z) dz =0$ based on the problem statement and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z) dz = 1$ because it's a density function.

for **variance**:

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x - \mu)^2 f\{ (x - \mu) / \sigma \} / \sigma dx$

=$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sigma^2 z^2 f(z) dz  $

$= \sigma^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty z^2 f(z) dz  $

for the same change of variable as before.

since $var(z) = E[z^2] - E[z]^2$ and based on the problem statement we know that $var(z) = 1$ and $E[z] = 0$ then we can conclude that $E[z^2] =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty z^2 f(z) dz = 1$

putting it back in the equation we can conclude:

$var(x) = \sigma^2 *1 = \sigma^2$